# How do i make the last element in my linked list point to null in C

Tags: c, linked-list

I was trying to implement a linked list in C. In my linked list i want to insert elements to the start of the list, so i have the following method...

```
void insertToStart(LinkedList* list, Student st)
{
  LinkedListNode* newNode = (LinkedListNode*)malloc(sizeof(LinkedListNode)); 
  newNode->data = st;
  newNode->next = list->head;
  list->head = newNode;
}
```

my problem comes when I try to print my list... i get an infinite loop. This is my printList method

```
void printList(LinkedList* list)
{
  LinkedListNode* current;
  current = list->head;
  while(current != NULL)
  {
    printf("Name: %s ID: %d\n", current->data.name , current->data.ID);
    current = current->next;
  }
}
```

If figured it might be because the last element's next in my list does not point to null but I don't know how to make the last element's next point to null. How can I do this?
This is my header file...

```
#ifndef LINKEDLIST_H
#define LINKEDLIST_H

typedef struct{
  char name[20];
  int ID;
} Student;

typedef struct LinkedListNode{
  Student data;
  struct LinkedListNode* next;
} LinkedListNode;

typedef struct {
  LinkedListNode* head;
} LinkedList;

void mallocList(LinkedList* list);
void insertToStart(LinkedList* list, Student st);
void printList(LinkedList* list);

#endif
```

Comment: My crystal ball thinks that you forgot to set `head` to `NULL` when you created the initial, empty, list.

Comment: show `void mallocList(LinkedList* list)` and call this.

Comment: Please show how you call `mallocList`, `insertToStart` and `printList`. Also read about this: [mcve]

Comment: You don't want anything to "point to null" (useless for a linked list), you want some pointers to **be** NULLs.

Comment: Given the "infinite loop" vs a likely "crash and burn" for an indeterminate pointer, coupled with the apparent configure-this parameter interface for `mallocList`, I'd almost wager `mallocList` is someone's idea of setting up some unnecessary  "sentinel" node for the initial `head`, and they setup a single-node circular list while doing so. Of course, without code to reproduce this, wags (wild ass guesses) as the best you can get, and that was mine. Best of luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should initialize `list->head` to `NULL`.
Then as you add elements to the head of the list with `insertToStart`, the last element in the list will keep its `next` equal to `NULL`, and thus you will have a correct tail on your list.
You also have to be careful if you also want to implement the removal of nodes from the list. In this case, make sure that when you remove the tail node its previous node has its `next` pointer set to `NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

NULL == 0. So set your `next` ptr to 0. To represent the termination of your linked list.

i.e

```
next = 0;
```

Comment: This is not correct, with the first line, `newNode->next` points to the old list head, and with the second line, `list->head` is moved to point to the new list head, which is now `newNode`.

Comment: Apologies you are correct. Have removed that statement.